# Android OrmLite Query all rows in table A and not in Table B

Tags: android, database, sqlite, join, ormlite

I have two tables

```
class A {
   String id;
   String name;
}

class B {
   String id;
   String password;
}

 QueryBuilder<A, String> aQb = ADao.queryBuilder();
 QueryBuilder<B, String> bQb = BDao.queryBuilder();
```

how do I query all the rows in table A whose id does not exist in class B using OrmLite?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw query:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = aDao
                .queryRaw("SELECT * FROM tableA t1 LEFT JOIN tableB t2 ON t2.id = t1.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL");
List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();
```

Comment: `*` also returns B's columns. And ORMLite supports left joins and NULL checks.